# AngularJS when user presses back button

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've search all round and it seems I can't get a clear simple answer on this.
Basically I'm having problems with a search/filter field, user enters text and it filters that page. The filter works on every page.

Now when they press any navigation item it clears the search text / model value. I had to manually fire onclick events for this and create a function.

My problem is, is that when the user pressed the browser 'back button' the input text is not getting cleared.

Are there any simple events like:

```
if(usersPressedBackButton){
//Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one could provide a clear answer on this, so I created my own.

I had a create a boolean that detected when the user searched form another page.

Parent Controller:

```
$scope.searchFilterText = '';
$scope.fromSearchClick = false;
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function() 
    {
        if(!$scope.fromSearchClick){
            $scope.clearFilterSearchText();
        }
        $scope.fromSearchClick = false;

    });
```

Child Controller - Or page you don't/do want the search to be cleared.

```
//In any function
$scope.$parent.fromSearchClick = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code into your controller:

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
    if ($scope.yourinputfield.$dirty) {
        $scope.yourinputfield = "";
        $scope.yourinputfield.$setPristine();
    }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The search modal/field still contains the text.